Lock rows on a google sheet when a tick box is ticked and various other data validations are already in place
I would like a row to lock when a check box is ticked.
I have a script but I can still edit the row when I tick the check box in Col6.
I need all rows to be locked for everyone including myself (the owner) when the check box in Col6 is ticked. If it is un ticked it is fine to edit the rest of the row.
I think I am missing something obvious so sorry if this is a daft mistake on my part.
This is the script I have currently.
function lockRow (e){
const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
if (e.range.columnStart != 6) return;
let protection = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getMaxColumns()).protect();
protection.removeEditor(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}


If anyone could assist I would be most grateful, thank you in advance :-)

This is potentially possible without scripting using plain data validation. You haven't shown an example of your sheet so this is a generic example you would need to adapt to your situation:

Add tick boxes to a column for as many rows as required by selecting cells in column F (=column 6) then selecting Insert/Tick box
Select Data/Data validation, then 'Add rule', 'Apply to range' and select the range of cells in the same rows as your checkboxes that are to be subject to the validation rule (e.g. Gx:Zx)
Set 'criteria' to 'custom formula is' and in in the formula box use =indirect(address(row(),6))=false
Selct 'Advanced options', tick 'Show help text for a selected cell' and replace the text in the field with something like 'Locked by tick box'
Ensure that 'Reject the input' (under 'If the data is invalid') is selected
If you wish to have the cells either side of the tick box column locked (not just those to the right as shown in my example), you will need to repeat steps 2-5 for the range of cells to the left  of the tick box column.

The results of this will be that if a tick box is ticked, attempts to enter any data into cells in the same row will bring up a 'Locked by tick box' message. All cells that had data added prior to the relevant tick box being ticked will show a red mark in their upper-right corner indicating an error (because they are technically violating the data validation rule), however their contents will be maintained, and any attempts to change them will result in the 'Locked by tick box' message and the data reverting.

HI, Thank you but this didn't work and voided all the other data validations in the sheet. Think maybe I am doing something wrong.

Not sure how to show you the example of the sheet.
